# React js production resource not found on reload or manual url mapping

Tags: reactjs, nginx, vert.x

We have a host 1 which acts a react web server and our build folder resides there, on host 1. We have host2 on which we have nginx configured as reverse proxy for host 1 which has our react app(static pages) and api server.

```
location / {
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass https://host1:8444/;
    }
```

When we access https://host2/ from url, we get the react app (on host) we can access the routes https://host2/app/users from the app that is by clicking the links in the app, but when we access https://host2/app/users or any other path through url, we get `Resource not found` error in the browser. What are we doing wrong?
One possible problem seems to be because of Nginx not having the mapping for each individual paths.

What we tried:
map all my URIs ( paths ) inside nginx file, but it seems to be not the correct way as the paths will be too many and keep growing.

Example

```
location /users/search {
// code block
}

location /posts/search {
// code block
}
```

Which is not the right way.
Someone has any thoughts for such deployment procedures?

Comment: Are you sure you correctly understand how react routing works?

Comment: Seems like you may have an issue with where & how you deployed your app. Take a look through the [CRA deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) docs to see if there's a relevant section for your server environment, i.e. what you are calling host 1 and 2 I think.

Comment: @RutgerVersteegden All I know of react router is when index.html loads up our react app loads up and once react app loads up as per the url the react router renders the page of the react application. Can you please correct me which part of react router I am wrong, so that I can have more clarity?